# EditText focus is lost while rotate the device landscape to portrait

Tags: android

In my application when click on the *search icon* in the `action bar` show a overlay layout in that layout contains `EditText` and `listview`.when enter some key word in the `Edittext` result will be shown in the `Listview` its work fine.but when i switch to *portrait* to *landscape* and tap the search again the `EditText` in the overlay is not getting the focus.the underlying layout getting focused(it contain a `scrollview`) 
Any one please suggest a solution. I am using the `onConfigurationChanged` to handle the rotation.

Comment: Have you tried requestFocus() method?

Comment: post the code of your activity

Comment: post activity  code with logcat

Comment: ya i try with requestFocus() method but not working. i writen the searchoverlay function in the MainActivity and onConfigurationChange method in the another fragment.